# Pet Spaniel Getting Aggressive When Being Sniffed

Tags: dogs, aggression

We've had our male Cocker Spaniel since a puppy and he's now 8 years old. However, more recently he has become much less tolerant of other dogs, which I do kind of get with getting old. However, we have noticed something more specific. He is more than happy to greet another dog and sniff their behind but when another dog does this to him he gets aggressive (although not all the time). We are currently staying at a rented holiday home (neutral location) with friends that also have a male dog (Border Collie) and it has been a bit of a strain at times as our friends' dog is lovely. He's met this other dog on numerous occasions but he does get aggressive when he approaches from behind and tries to sniff, even when it's not a surprise.

Any help would be appreciated.